# Memu emulator error showing in the application

Tags: android, ufw, data-loss, emulation, internationalization

My memu player shows weird massages(errors) saying "unfortunately memu lucher has stopped" or "unfortunately google.service.apps.gapps has stopped." I cant open any app and the time I open one of them it suddenly closes and the mentioned messages appear. And I can not even have access my data options to for example uninstall apps. I cant do anything.
I will be thankful if you help me.